# Nautilus (context menu) script to quickly rename a file using $RANDOM - but how?

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus, nautilus-script

I want to add a context menu entry to nautilus with a custom script but I don't really know how to write this (I'm very inexperienced with this stuff).

Basically I want to rename selected files with `$RANDOM` using `mv -n` while keeping the file suffix. Anyone know how to that?

I know I have to place it in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`, that's for sure!

Edit: Wow, I'm (positively) overwhelmed with your suggestions, all of them work great! Thank you Feldspar, David & pa4080!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script I made:

```
#!/bin/bash

# FileRNG.sh by feldspar15523
# Feel free to edit this as much as you want.

IFS=$'\n'
for i in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
    nameInput="$(basename -- "$i")"
    extension="${nameInput#*.}"
    filePath="$i"

    case "$(basename -- "$nameInput")" in
    *.* )
        mv -nT -- "$filePath" "$PWD/$RANDOM.$extension"
        ;;
    * )
        mv -nT -- "$filePath" "$PWD/$RANDOM"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

This is a fully functional script that you can use.  It respects extensions even if it does not have one.  Works with multiple files.  Be sure to allow it to be executed with `chmod +x FileRNG.sh`

Comment: I fixed a number of other issues. I can give you an individual run-down of them if you open a question on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: I understand it.  I really should have quoted the variables, `man` told me what `-T` does, and google told me what `IFS` is.  While testing I tried `for` but it did not work, but that is what `IFS` does.

Comment: The only disadvantage of `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` over `$@` is that the former doesn't handle file names with new-line characters correctly. That would be one further improvement that my solution uses (`for i; do` is equivalent to `for i in "$@"; do`).

Comment: Is it even possible to put a newline in a file name?  `echo "foo" > "file\n name"` and `touch` do not do it.

Comment: Try `touch foo$'\n'bar && printf '»%s«\n' *`. Most tools will escape special characters in file names, e. g. `ls` and `stat`.

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus supplies selected paths to scripts as program arguments. The following script will rename the paths supplied as program arguments to random files (while preserving the file extension) and inform the user of the result via Zenity (or on the command line without X):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

for source; do
    case "$source" in
        */*) dir="${source%/*}";;
        *) dir=.;;
    esac

    basename="${source##*/}"
    case "$basename" in
        ?*.*) extension=".${basename##*.}"; basename="${basename%.*}";;
        *) extension=;;
    esac

    message_type=info
    destination="$(exec mktemp --tmpdir="$dir" --suffix="$extension" XXXXXXXXXX 2>&1)" ||
        { rv=$?; message="$destination"; false; } &&
    message="$(exec mv -vT -- "$source" "$destination" 2>&1)" ||
        { rv="${rv-$?}"; message_type=error; }

    if [ -n "${DISPLAY-}" ]; then
        zenity "--$message_type" --no-markup --title="${0##*/}" --text="$message"
    else
        printf '%s: %s: %s\n' "${0##*/}" "$message_type" "$message" >&2
    fi

    [ -z "${rv-}" ] || exit "$rv"
done
```

It uses `mktemp` instead of `$RANDOM` to select the destination path because

1. `mktemp` assures that the target file doesn't exist and
2. because it works with POSIX-compliant Bourne shells that don't support Bash’s special `$RANDOM` variable and no-clobber extensions.

Thus the random names aren't numerical but consist of a sequence of 8 random alpha-numerical characters. If you really want to use `$RANDOM` I can create a variant based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, which current version uses the first 10 applicable characters from the endless supply of pseudo-random characters in `/dev/urandom`. This behaviour could be modified by editing of line 21 and 22.

- The previous version, that uses only `$RANDOM`, is available within [the history](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/959405/3).
- The script can handle single and multiple selected files and directories.
- When the item is a file there are 3 options:

  - `file.ext` → `$RANDOM`
  - `file.ext` → `$RANDOM.ext`
  - `file.ext` → `file-$RANDOM.ext`
- When the item is a directory, the above options are reduced to 2:

  - `dir` → `$RANDOM`
  - `dir` → `dir-$RANDOM`
- The script uses `zenity` to ask for the user's preferences, according to the above options. Also if the item is a directory there is an additional question, that has 5 seconds time out.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

IFS_BAK=$IFS
IFS=$'\t\n'
FILE_LIST=($NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS)
IFS=$IFS_BAK

opt1="file.ext → \$RANDOM | dir → \$RANDOM"
opt2="file.ext → \$RANDOM.ext | dir → \$RANDOM"
opt3="file.ext → file-\$RANDOM.ext | dir → dir-\$RANDOM"

OPT=$(zenity --list  --width=400 --height=170 \
             --text "Random file and directory renamer: ${#FILE_LIST[@]} item(s) are selected." \
             --radiolist --column "Pick" \
             --column "File opinions | Dir opinions" FANSE "$opt1" TRUE "$opt2" FALSE "$opt3")

if [ "$OPT" == "0" ]; then exit 1; fi

for item in "${FILE_LIST[@]}"; do

        URANDOM=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9a-zA-Z!@$%_+-' | head -c 10)
        #URANDOM=$RANDOM

        if [ -f "$item" ]; then

                DIR="$(dirname "${item}")"
                FILE_NAME="$(basename "${item}")"
                EXT="${FILE_NAME##*.}"
                NAME="${FILE_NAME%.*}"

                if [ "$EXT" == "$NAME" ]; then EXT=""; else EXT=".$EXT"; fi

                if   [ "$OPT" == "$opt1" ]; then mv "$item" "$DIR/$URANDOM"
                elif [ "$OPT" == "$opt2" ]; then mv "$item" "$DIR/$URANDOM$EXT"
                elif [ "$OPT" == "$opt3" ]; then mv "$item" "$DIR/$NAME-$URANDOM$EXT"
                else zenity --info --text "Something went wrong!"
                fi

        elif [ -d "$item" ]; then

                DIR=$(dirname "${item}")
                DIR_NAME=$(basename "${item}")

                Q=`$(zenity --question --timeout 5 \
                            --text "The selected item \{ $DIR_NAME \} is a directory. \nHow to proceed\?" \
                            --cancel-label="Don't rename" --ok-label="Rename") && echo "Rename" || echo "Leave"` #zenity --info --text "$Q"

                if [ "$Q" == "Rename" ]; then
                        if   [ "$OPT" == "$opt1" ]; then mv "$item" "$DIR/$URANDOM"
                        elif [ "$OPT" == "$opt2" ]; then mv "$item" "$DIR/$URANDOM"
                        elif [ "$OPT" == "$opt3" ]; then mv "$item" "$DIR/$DIR_NAME-$URANDOM"
                        else zenity --info --text "Something went wrong!"
                        fi
                fi
        else
                zenity --info --text "Something went wrong!"
        fi
done
```

Here is the demo:

[image]

References:

- [Bash: Generating a random LETTERS sequence](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-generating-a-random-letters-sequence-880311/)
- [Bash: Generate random alphanumeric string](https://gist.github.com/earthgecko/3089509)

Comment: [Nice loop.](https://askubuntu.com/a/960322/566421)