# How do I add alternating strings to filenames and renumber them pairwise?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

Using a high-throughput microscope, we produce thousands of images. Let's say our system names them:

```
ome0001.tif
ome0002.tif
ome0003.tif
ome0004.tif
ome0005.tif
ome0006.tif
ome0007.tif
ome0008.tif
ome0009.tif
ome0010.tif
ome0011.tif
ome0012.tif
...
```

We would like to alternatively insert `c1` and `c2` with respect to the numerical value of the images, and then change the original numbering so that each successive `c1` and `c2` harbor the same incremental number, respecting numerical order (1, then 2... then 9, then 10) rather than alphanumeric order (1, then 10, then 2...).

In my example, that would give:

```
ome0001c1.tif
ome0001c2.tif
ome0002c1.tif
ome0002c2.tif
ome0003c1.tif
ome0003c2.tif
ome0004c1.tif
ome0004c2.tif
ome0005c1.tif
ome0005c2.tif
ome0006c1.tif
ome0006c2.tif
...
```

We have not been able to do that via terminal command-line (biologist speaking...).

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify this part `(1, then 2... then 9, then 10)` of your statement

Comment: For my understanding: `ome0001.tif` >  `ome0001c1.tif` and `ome0002.tif` >  `ome0001c2.tif` and so on ? Curious to the type of microscope.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To answer all questions: The scope is controlled via MicroManager2. This weird numbering is because of the hightroughput settings we have to use to not go over the RAM available during acquisition (16Go)

Comment: The two first images (ome.0000.tif and ome.0001.tif) should be renamed ome.0000c1.tif and ome.0000c2.tif, the two following ones (ome.0002.tif and ome.0003.tif)  should be renamed ome.0001c1.tif and ome.0001c2.tif, and so on. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not sure if that makes it clear to me... What is the origin of the double mention for each? they are not double in the example's source.

Comment: Ah, wait that does :)

Comment: @PhilippeP In the post you have `ome0001.tif` as the first filename, and my answer is written for that case (which is part of why the arithmetic is so ugly). Is your first filename actually `ome0000.tif`, such that you want `ome0000.tif` to become `ome0000c1.tif`, and `ome0001.tif` to become `ome0000c2.tif`, etc.? Do the filenames have `.` after `ome`? I'm asking these things because in [that comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960234/add-alterning-strings-to-files-and-renumbering-pairwise/960258#comment1534270_960234) you say `ome.0000.tif` and `ome.0001.tif` are your "two first images."

Comment: Again, sorry for the confusion... The numbering does indeed start at ome0000, not ome0001 as I incorrectly stated in my example. But we can handle that, and your solution worked great. And there are no dot after ome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### `rename` performs bulk renaming, and it can do the arithmetic you need.

Different GNU/Linux distributions have different commands called `rename`, with different syntax and capabilities. In Debian, Ubuntu, and *some* other OSes, [**`rename`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/prename.1.html) is the Perl renaming utility `prename`. It is quite well suited to this task.

First I recommend telling `rename` to just *show* you what it would do, by running it with the `-n` flag:

```bash
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf("%04dc%d", int(($& - 1) \/ 2) + 1, 2 - $& % 2)/e' ome????.tif
```

That should show you:

```
rename(ome0001.tif, ome0001c1.tif)
rename(ome0002.tif, ome0001c2.tif)
rename(ome0003.tif, ome0002c1.tif)
rename(ome0004.tif, ome0002c2.tif)
rename(ome0005.tif, ome0003c1.tif)
rename(ome0006.tif, ome0003c2.tif)
rename(ome0007.tif, ome0004c1.tif)
rename(ome0008.tif, ome0004c2.tif)
rename(ome0009.tif, ome0005c1.tif)
rename(ome0010.tif, ome0005c2.tif)
rename(ome0011.tif, ome0006c1.tif)
rename(ome0012.tif, ome0006c2.tif)
```

Assuming that's  what you want, go ahead and run it without the `-n` flag (i.e., just remove `-n`):

```bash
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%04dc%d", int(($& - 1) \/ 2) + 1, 2 - $& % 2)/e' ome????.tif
```

That command is somewhat ugly--though still more elegant than using a loop in your shell--and perhaps someone with more Perl experience than I have will post a prettier solution.

***I highly recommend [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli)'s tutorial [Bulk renaming files in Ubuntu; the briefest of introductions to the rename command](https://thepcspy.com/read/bulk-rename-files-in-ubuntu/), for a gentle intro to writing `rename` commands.***

---

#### How that specific `rename` command works:

Here's what `s/\d+/sprintf("%04dc%d", int(($& - 1) \/ 2) + 1, 2 - $& % 2)/e` does:

- The leading `s` means to search for text to replace.
- The regular expression `/\d+/` matches one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`). This matches your `0001`, `0002`, and so forth.
- The command `sprintf("%04dc%d", int(($& - 1) / 2) + 1, 2 - $& % 2)` is built. `$&` represents the match. `/` normally ends the replacement text, but `\/` makes a literal `/` (which is division, as detailed below).
- The trailing `/e` means to *evaluate* the replacement text as code.
  (Try running it with just `/` instead of `/e` at the end, *but make sure to keep the `-n` flag!*)

Thus your new filenames are the return values of `sprintf("%04dc%d", int(($& - 1) \/ 2) + 1, 2 - $& % 2)`. So what's going on there?

- `sprintf` returns formatted text. It first argument is the *format string* into which values are placed. `%04d` consumes the first argument and formats it as an integer 4 characters wide. `%4d` would omit leading zeros, hence `%04d` is needed. Not being covered by any `%`, `c` means just a literal letter `c`. Then `%d` consumes the second argument and formats it as an integer (with default formatting).
- `int(($& - 1) / 2) + 1` subtracts 1 from the number extracted from the original filename, divides it by 2, truncates the fractional portion (`int` does that), then adds 1. That arithmetic sends `0001` and `0002` to `0001`, `0003` and `0004` to `0002`, `0005` and `0006` to `0003`, and so forth.
- `2 - $& % 2` takes the remainder of dividing the number extracted from the original filename by 2 (`%` does that), which is 0 if it's even and 1 if it's odd. It then subtracts that from 2. This arithmetic sends `0001` to `1`, `0002` to `2`, `0003` to `1`, `0004` to `2`, and so forth.

Finally, `ome????.tif` is a [glob](https://foldoc.org/glob) that [your shell expands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) to a list of all the filenames in the current directory that start with `ome`, end in `.tif`, and have exactly four of any characters in between.

This list is passed to the `rename` command, which will attempt to rename (or with `-n`, tell you how it would rename) all of the files whose names contain a match to the pattern `\d+`.

- From your description, it doesn't sound like you have any files in that directory named that way but with some of the characters not digits.
- But if you do then you can replace `\d+` with `\d{4}` in the regular expression appearing in the commands shown above, to ensure they aren't renamed, or just inspect the output produced with `-n` carefully, which you should be doing anyway.
- I wrote `\d+` instead of `\d{4}` to avoid making the command more complex than necessary. (There are many different ways to write it.)

Comment: Thanks a LOT Eliah! Not only does your solution (rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%04dc%d", int(($& - 1) \/ 2) + 1, 2 - $& % 2)/e' ome????.tif) work perfectly, but also very quickly. We renamed 18000 files in a few seconds. Thanks also to Zanna, and more generally to this community. We'll look into Oli's tutorial Bulk renaming files in Ubuntu to hopefully become able to rename things ourselves from now on. Philippe.

Answer (score 6):

I used a way to do this in Bash based on the idea that if the number in the filename is even, we want to divide it by two, and add `c2`, and if the number is odd, we want to add one to it and then divide by two, and add `c1`. Treating odd and even numbered files separately like this is much lengthier than [Eliah Kagan's Bash method](https://askubuntu.com/a/960322/527764) and I agree that using `rename` as in [this other answer by Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/a/960258/527764) is the smart way, but this kind of approach might be useful in some situations.

A slight advantage to this, over using a range like `{0000...0012}` is that it only tries to operate on existing files, so it won't complain if the files don't exist. However, you still get illogically numbered files if there are any gaps. See the second part of my answer for a way that doesn't have this problem.

In one line it looks awful:

```bsh
for f in *; do g="${f%.tif}"; h="${g#ome}"; if [[ $(bc <<< "$h%2") == 0 ]]; then printf -v new "ome%04dc2.tif" "$(bc <<< "$h/2")" ; echo mv -vn -- "$f" "$new"; else printf -v new "ome%04dc1.tif" "$(bc <<< "($h+1)/2")"; echo mv -vn -- "$f" "$new"; fi; done
```

Here's that as a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do 
    g="${f%.tif}"
    h="${g#ome}"

    if [[ $(bc <<< "$h%2") == 0 ]]; then 
         printf -v new "ome%04dc2.tif" "$(bc <<< "$h/2")"
         echo mv -vn -- "$f" "$new"
    else
         printf -v new "ome%04dc1.tif" "$(bc <<< "($h+1)/2")"
         echo mv -vn -- "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```

The `echo`es prepending the `mv` statements are just for testing. Remove them to actually rename the files if you're seeing what you want being done.

#### Notes

```bsh
g="${f%.tif}"     # strip off the extension
h="${g#ome}"      # strip off the letters... now h contains the number
```

Test that the number is even (ie dividing by 2 gives no remainder)

```bsh
if [[ $(bc <<< "$h%2") == 0 ]]; then
```

I've used `bc`, which won't try to treat numbers with leading zeroes as octal numbers, although I could have just stripped off the zeroes with another string expansion since I'm going to format the numbers fixed-width anyway.

Next construct the new name for the even-numbered files:

```bsh
printf -v new "ome%04dc2.tif" "$(bc <<< "$h/2")"
```

`%04d` will be replaced by the number output by `bc <<< "$h/2"` in 4 digit format, padded with leading zeroes (so 0 = 0000, 10 = 0010, etc).

Rename the original file with the constructed new name

```bsh
echo mv -vn -- "$f" "$new"
```

`-v` for verbose, `-n` for no-clobber (don't overwrite files that already have the intended name, if they exist) and `--` to prevent errors from filenames beginning with `-` (but since the rest of my script expects your files to be named `ome[somenumber].tif` I guess I'm just adding it out of habit).

---

#### Filling the gaps

After some tinkering and more help from Eliah Kagan, I worked out more succinct way to increment the names that has the advantage of filling the gaps. The problem with this way is that only increments a number, does some simple arithmetic on that number, formats it, and puts it in the filename. Bash thinks (so to speak) "ok, here's the next file, I'll give it the next name", without paying any attention to the original filename. This means **it creates new names that don't relate to the old names**, so you will not be able to logically undo the renaming, and the files will be renamed in the correct order only if their names are already such that they will be processed in the right order. This is the case in your example, which has fixed-width zero-padded numbers, but if you had files named, say, `2`, `8`, `10`, `45` they would be processed in the order `10`, `2`, `45`, `8`, which is probably not what you want.

If this approach is suitable for you given all that, you can do it like this:

```bsh
i=0; for f in ome????.tif; do ((i++)); printf -v new "ome%04dc%d.tif" $(((i+1)/2)) $(((i+1)%2+1)); echo mv -vn "$f" "$new"; done
```

or

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
i=0

for f in ome????.tif; do 
    ((i++))
    printf -v new "ome%04dc%d.tif" $(((i+1)/2)) $(((i+1)%2+1))
    echo mv -vn "$f" "$new"
done
```

#### Notes

- `i=0` initiate a variable
- `((i++))` increment the variable by one (this counts iterations of the loop)
- `printf -v new` put the following statement into the variable `new`
- `"ome%04dc%d.tif"` the new filename with the number formats that will be replaced with the subsequently mentioned numbers
- `$(((i+1)/2))` the number of times the loop has been run plus one, divided by 2

  This works on the basis that Bash only does integer division, so when we divide an odd number by 2, we get the same answer as we got when we divided the preceding even number by 2:

  ```bsh
  $ echo $((2/2))
  1
  $ echo $((3/2))
  1
  ```
- `$(((i+1)%2+1))` The remainder after dividing number of times the loop has been run plus one by two, plus one. This means, if the number of the iteration is odd (eg the first run), the output is `1`, and if the number of the iteration is even (eg the second run), the output is `2`, giving `c1` or `c2`
- I used `i=0` because then at any point during the run, the value of `i` will be *the number of times the loop has been run*, which might be useful for debugging as it will also be the ordinal number of the file being processed (i.e. when `i=69`, we are processing the 69th file). However, we can simplify the arithmetic by starting with a different `i`, for example:

  ```bsh
  i=2; for f in ome????.tif; do printf -v new "ome%04dc%d.tif" $((i/2)) $((i%2+1)); echo mv -vn "$f" "$new"; ((i++)); done
  ```

  There are lots of ways to do this :)
- `echo` just for testing - remove if you see the result you want.

Here's an example of what this method does:

```bsh
$ ls
ome0002.tif  ome0004.tif  ome0007.tif  ome0009.tif  ome0010.tif  ome0012.tif  ome0019.tif  ome0100.tif  ome2996.tif
$ i=0; for f in ome????.tif; do ((i++)); printf -v new "ome%04dc%d.tif" $(((i+1)/2)) $(((i+1)%2+1)); echo mv -vn "$f" "$new"; done 
mv -vn ome0002.tif ome0001c1.tif
mv -vn ome0004.tif ome0001c2.tif
mv -vn ome0007.tif ome0002c1.tif
mv -vn ome0009.tif ome0002c2.tif
mv -vn ome0010.tif ome0003c1.tif
mv -vn ome0012.tif ome0003c2.tif
mv -vn ome0019.tif ome0004c1.tif
mv -vn ome0100.tif ome0004c2.tif
mv -vn ome2996.tif ome0005c1.tif
```

Answer (score 5):

#### You can write a shell loop for this, if you really want to.

If you want a command that works on systems that don't have `rename` or whose `rename` command is not `prename`, or you want it to be somewhat more readily understood by people who know Bash but not Perl, or for some other reason you want to implement this as a loop in your shell that calls the [**`mv`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mv.1.html) command, you can. (Otherwise, I recommend the `rename` method in [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960258/22949) over this.)

Ubuntu has Bash 4, in which [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) preserves leading zeros, so `{0001..0012}` expands to `0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 0010 0011 0012`. **This is appropriate only in situations where you actually have all files in a range.** Based on the problem description in your question, that appears to be the case. Otherwise, it would still work, but you'd get a whole bunch of error messages for the gaps, which would make it hard to notice any other errors that might actually be important. **Replace `0012` with your actual upper bound.**

Since [`echo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(command)) appears before `mv`, this command just prints the `mv` commands that would be run, without actually running them:<sup>**1**</sup>

```bash
for i in {0001..0012}; do echo mv -n "ome$i.tif" "$(printf 'ome%04dc%d.tif' "$(((10#$i - 1) / 2 + 1))" "$((2 - 10#$i % 2))")"; done
```

This uses the same basic idea as in [my `rename` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960258/22949), both as far as the arithmetic goes, and for the meaning of `%04d` and `%d` in the format strings. This could be done with `{1..12}`, but then it would be even more complicated because it would require two `$(` `)` command substitutions with `printf`, instead of just one.

Please keep in mind that the `-n` in `rename -n` doesn't mean the same thing as the `-n` in `mv -n`. Running `rename -n` doesn't move files at all. Running `mv -n` moves files unless it would have to overwrite an existing file at the destination in order to do so, which is to say that `mv -n` gives you the safety you get automatically with `rename` (unless you run `rename -f`). **To make the command shown above actually move files, remove the `echo`**:

```bash
for i in {0001..0012}; do mv -n "ome$i.tif" "$(printf 'ome%04dc%d.tif' "$(((10#$i - 1) / 2 + 1))" "$((2 - 10#$i % 2))")"; done
```

---

#### Here's how that Bash loop works:

`for i in {0001..0012}` runs the commands after `do` twelve times, with `i` taking on a different value each time. This loop only happens to have one such command before `done`, which signifies the end of the loop body. (Conceptually, when control hits that `done`, it moves on to the next iteration of the loop, with `i` as the next value.) That one command is:

```bash
mv -n "ome$i.tif" "$(printf 'ome%04dc%d.tif' "$(((10#$i - 1) / 2 + 1))" "$((2 - 10#$i % 2))")"
```

- `$i` appears a few times in the loop. This is [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), and it is replaced with the current value of `i`.
- `ome$i.tif` expands to one of `ome0001.tif`, `ome0002.tif`, `ome0003.tif`, etc., depending on which value `i` has. Including the leading 0s by writing `{0001..0012}` instead of `{1..12}` makes this argument to `mv`, which gives the old name of the file, simple to write.
- `$(` `)` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). Inside it I run a `printf` command that outputs the desired text of the second argument to `mv`, which gives the new name of the file. The whole thing is enclosed in [`"` `"` quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) so unwanted expansions--specifically, [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)--are avoided. In command substitution, `$(...)` is replaced with *output* produced by running the command `...`.

The command that outputs the destination filename is thus:

```bash
printf 'ome%04dc%d.tif' "$(((10#$i - 1) / 2 + 1))" "$((2 - 10#$i % 2))"
```

- `%04d` and `%d` have the same meaning as in Perl's `sprintf` function that [used from `rename`](https://askubuntu.com/a/960258/22949).
- Each of the two arguments use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to perform calculations. The whole `$((...))` is replaced with the result of evaluating the expression `...`.
- `10#$i` takes the value of `i` (`$i`) and [treats it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) as a [base-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) number (`10#`). This is necessary here because Bash treats numbers with leading `0`s as [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).<sup>**2**</sup> Inside `$((` `))` you can typically just write a variable's name to compute with it (i.e., `i` instead of `$i`), but `$i` is also supported and `10#$i` is one of the few cases where it is needed inside `$((` `))`.
- The arithmetic here is the same as I [used from `rename`](https://askubuntu.com/a/960258/22949), except that division in Bash is automatically integer division--it automatically truncates the fractional portion--so it is not necessary to use anything corresponding to Perl's `int` function.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>A bug in the [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting) used for Bash code on this site currently causes everything after the `#` to be grayed out. An unquoted `#` usually starts a [comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)) in Bash, though [in this case it doesn't](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic). You need not worry about this--your Bash interpreter won't make the same mistake.</sub>

<sup>**2**</sup> <sub>Perl actually treats numbers with leading `0`s as octal, too. However, with `rename`, the match variable `$&` is actually a string--this is *text* processing, after all. Perl allows strings to be used as though they were numbers, and when it does, leading `0`s in the *string* do not cause it to be treated as an octal number! Comparing the `rename` way to this longer, more difficult, less robust shell-loop method brings a common observation to mind: *Perl is weird, but it gets the job done.*</sub>